# Rxjs. Nested conditional observable which pause "main" observable

Tags: rxjs

I have obserable:

```
const observable = new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next(1);
  subscriber.next(2);
  subscriber.next(3);
})
```

and I would like to  subscribe in such way:

```
observable.subscribe({
  next(x) { 
    console.log('got value ' + x); 
    if (x == 2) {
      const observable2 = new Observable(subscriber => {
       subscriber.next('a');
       subscriber.next('b');
       subscriber.next('c');
      })  
     observable2.subscribe(...)   
    }      
  },
  error(err) { console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err); },
  complete() { console.log('done'); }
});
```

I have Observable which "throw" some data and if data equal to some specific value i need to

1. Pause main Observable
2. Subscribe to Observable in if-block
3. Get some data from "conditional" Observable
4. Resume main Observable

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, handling observables this way will make it difficult to maintain the code in the long run. If you have multiple observables to subscribe to, you will also have to handle their subscription etc..

So, for this specific case, here's how I'd solve it:

```js
const source = of(1, 2, 3);

const subscription = source
  .pipe(
    /**
     * `Pause` the main observable
     * Won't to get the next emitted value until this inner subscription is done
     */
    concatMap(v => {
      // The if block
      if (v === 2) {
        // Getting some data from the condition
        return of('a', 'b', 'c');
      }

      return of('default value');
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.log('value received!', v))
```

`concatMap` is one of the [high order operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/).

It will also return an observable, whose subscription will **internally** be handled by `concatMap`.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bqbfow?devtoolsheight=60).

### Edit after reading the first comment

```js
const microS1$ = ...;

microS1$
 .pipe(
  // Insert your condition here
  filter(content => typeof content === 'string')
 )
 .subscribe(d => {
  // Send the data to the second microservice
  microserviceTwo.sendData(d);
 })
```

Comment: Yup, good advise but problem is that I don't have pre-defined values (1,2,3 or "a","b","c").

observable and observable2 are streaming data from another microservice. And if received data  from observable is content ( string) we pass that data to another microservice (observable 2)  which streaming another data

Comment: Thank you. Actually filter is not needed here, situation is: if data from first observer is not string we just save it to local variable (let document). If data is string - we send this data to second microservice which returns another data ( data2). Finally we add data2 to variable document and again - if data is not string - let document = data, if data is string - wait response from second microservice and append it to document...